# LiveUSB with CLONEZILLA and GPARTED : Which Distro?

Tags: live-usb, distributions, clonezilla

I need to find a stable distro which has, on its LiveUSB, both Clonezilla and Gparted, for Ubuntu 18.04 does not. Which LiveUSBs would have both?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? From your short description it is rather unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try MX Linux (https://mxlinux.org/), which is a Debian-based yet systemd-free distro. They offer a live CD environment that you can alter based on your own needs. The `MX Tools` packages include an `MX Live USB Maker` among other remastering tools. You run the live system, do your installs, updates, removals and settings. Write it to a new USB device and voila, you have a new live system that includes whatever software you like.

Steps to take are basically these:

1. Download the image
2. Write to a USB device or CD;
3. Boot into the live system (optionally even running it from RAM if you have enough to copy the whole lot into RAM);
4. Make any changes you like;
5. Use the remastering tool to write the 'current' live system to a new device or CD.

If you use a writable medium for the second (custom) system, you can also leave some space available for saving files using the persistence options. This may, for example, be useful if you want to make changes to other filesystems and want to make some backups before making changes (e.g. when using `e2fsck`, you could make backup copies of the superblock of have an undo file).

Edit:  any persistent filesystems are saved as compressed filesystems (in a single file) on the same partition as the other live system files, so you'll want to make that partition nicely big if you want to have much space available. Also, the slower persistence options are the safest and I have some memory of certain (slower) persistence options being much more effective when updating the root filesystem. Generally, make sure you install and update first, then reboot, immediately check if the new software is still there and then get all the configuration right. I've had a few funny moments losing applications, such as Rhythmbox (music player), only to find after re-installation that the saved radio stations were still there, as they had been saved.

Comment: Reason for latest edit? On the website I see no reference to "Devuan" at all. In fact, on the Migration page, they state explicitly that MX Linux 18 is based on Debian 9 (Stretch) and MX Linux 19 is based on Debian 10 (Buster). So I am puzzled where the inserted bits come from.

Comment: https://mxlinux.org/wiki/system/systemd/ explains MX Linux defaults not to use systemd. Here's an explanation from Devuan as to why some folks avoid systemd systemd https://devuan.org/os/init-freedom .